# How To Use A Directive In A Custom Input With ControlValueAccessor Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, controlvalueaccessor

I've been create a simple custom `input` component in my angular app use `ControlValueAccessor`. So, when I want to create a form `input` element, I don't have to call `<input />`, only call `<my-input>`.

I have a problem, when I use `<input />`, I can use `myDirective`. For example:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" myDirective />
```

But, when I use `my-input`, then I can't use `myDirective`. For example:

```html
<my-input formControlName="name" myDirective></my-input>
```

> *myDirective* dosn't work in my-input

This is `my-input` component use `ControlValueAccessor` code:

```js
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(()  => MyInputComponent ),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  onChange: () => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  value: string;

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value ? value : '';
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

**Updated:** `myDirective` code:

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})

export class MyDirective{
    constructor(private formControlName: FormControlName) { }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event']) 
    onInputChange() {
        this.formControlName.control.setValue(this.formControlName.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    }
}
```

Is there a way for `myDirective` to be used in the`my-input` component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post `myDirective` implementation

Comment: I've been add to my question before: `<my-input formControlName="name" myDirective></my-input>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're a problem with your directive. Inject a [NgControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl) and control this ngControl

```
export class MyDirective{
    constructor(private control: NgControl) { } //<--inject NgControl

    @HostListener('input', ['$event']) 
    onInputChange() {
        this.control.control.setValue(this.control.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    }
}
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7cg4w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy.directive.ts)

NOTE: Don't forget include in the module declarations

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, MyInputComponent,MyDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I really appreciate it, but I'm use `formGroup` and `formControlName`.

Comment: Titus, the directive is applied to a NgControl (a NgControl is a input with [(NgModel)], [formControl] **or** formControlName). In the stackblitz I use formControl to not create a formGroup, but the directive **works** also if you has a formGroup

Comment: Because I've been try your code above, and put `myDirective` in `my-input` selector: `<my-input formControlName="name" myDirective></my-input>` but it's not change the value. But I'm sure, from your code, it's working, that's why you answer my question and I see it, it's work. But in mys, use `formGroup` and `formControlName`, it's can't change the value. But thanks for your your response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz using a FormGroup. do you forget call to onChange(value) when change the value in your custom form control?

Comment: Sure, that's why I'm saying in the my question above. Please check it. It's working in `input` but not in `my-input`.

Comment: the problem is in your "my-input". To check, write in .html `{{myForm?.value|json}}` to see if it give you the correct value and check console errors

Answer (score 2):

## You can't directly but you can do some Hack with directives queries

According to the Angular Directives documentation:

> Decorator that marks a class as an Angular directive. You can define your own directives to attach custom behaviour to elements in the DOM.

a decorator is a behaviour attached to an element to the DOM, so it will affect the element wich use the directive.

BUT (and is a big BUT for a reason - check notes), you can hack this behaviour using directive queries.

BUT *remember* you must define specific directives which will work only with specific queries and cannot be used for any DOM element.

### The solution

The solution is based on the following:

> I want to define a directive which works on an element children, and not on the element itself.

You can use [@ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) and QueryList to check if you have some children with a specific directive.

For example, I have a background directive applied to input parent and a **CustomFormControlDirective** to query the children:

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  ContentChildren,
  ViewChildren,
  QueryList
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[customformcontrol]"
})
export class CustomFormControlDirective {
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}

@Directive({
  selector: "[backgroundColor]",
  queries: {
    contentChildren: new ContentChildren(CustomFormControlDirective),
    viewChildren: new ViewChildren(CustomFormControlDirective)
  }
})
export class BackgroundColorDirective {
  @Input()
  set backgroundColor(color: string) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  @ContentChildren(CustomFormControlDirective, { descendants: true })
  contentChildren: QueryList<CustomFormControlDirective>;
  viewChildren: QueryList<CustomFormControlDirective>;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // contentChildren is set
    console.log("%o", this.contentChildren);
  }
}
[...]
<div backgroundColor="red">
  <input customformcontrol />
</div>
```

Of course this directive will apply the bg color to the parent div:

[image: Div with red bg]]

So how can we set this property to the children?

We have the children inside our **contentChildren** variable:

[image: Console log]

So we need to apply the desired background to our children element, we can loop trough the query results and try to apply the style:

```js
  [...]
  _backgroundColor = null;
  @Input()
  set backgroundColor(color: string) {
    /// save the bg color instead of apply style
    this._backgroundColor = color;
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.contentChildren.length) {
      /// then loop through childrens to apply style
      this.contentChildren.forEach(customFormControl => {
        customFormControl.elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this._backgroundColor;
      });
    }
  }
  [...]
```

And it will apply the style to childrens:
[image: Children with red bg]

also if there are more than 1 children:
[image: More fancy red bgs]

## Notes

- this is an example, don't take this implementation as-is, you might define your own method or use a better one, but try to understand the QueryList selectors and ContentChildren.
- using a custom directive to fetch childrens might not be necessary, you might use ReactiveForm directives directly (AbstractControlDirective / FormControlDirective) but I don't think they will let you access the DOM as it is private.
- these directives will work only with children, so you might choose a better naming convention (e.g. ApplyToControlBackgroundDirective)

Comment: And remember, this solutions works with any arbitrary nested element, not only with Reactive Forms elements